# Remote log out of Google Apps

Tags: security, whatsapp-messenger, gmail, remote-control, airdroid

I had to leave my phone at a repair store and give them them the lock screen password. Is there anything I can do remotely to secure certain apps, such as Google Drive, Keep and Gmail? I know you can logout of Gmail for other devices but I'm not sure if it counts on Android since it's so integrated. Also what about apps like Whatsapp and Snapchat?

I can log in with Airdroid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your Google account password. This will sign you out of your Google account on all of your devices, preventing the repair person from sending an email in your name, loading new emails, creating new Drive documents, etc.

In fact, there's a whole Google support page on your issue [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en).

Comment: but will that affect the gmail app on the phone?

Comment: @Celeritas Edited answer, check it again!